# I need help to authenticate the user ,because anybody can log in to the app

Tags: java, android

My problem is that i want a user to get authenticated, by getting the token from the the server to verify that the user is signed up , but it seems that anyone can log in how can i authenticate users so that only the members(signed up users) can only log in .
My problem is that i want a user to get authenticated, by getting the token from the the server to verify that the user is signed up , but it seems that anyone can log in how can i authenticate users so that only the members(signed up users) can only log in .

```
public class login extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView register;
    EditText email, password;
    Button registerbutton;
    Api newapi ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        register = findViewById(R.id.text_view_register_here);
        password = findViewById(R.id.edit_text_password_login);
        email = findViewById(R.id.text_email_loginhapa);
        registerbutton = findViewById(R.id.button_sign_in);
        register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(login.this, sign_up.class));
            }
        });
        registerbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String mEmail = email.getText().toString().trim();
                String mPassword = password.getText().toString().trim();
                userLogin(mEmail, mPassword);
            }
        });
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://uat.elma.bz/revenueapi/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        newapi  = retrofit.create(Api.class);
    }

    private void userLogin(String mEmail, String mPassword) {
        if (!isValidEmail(mEmail)) {
            email.setError("You are not a User Sign up to proceed");
            email.requestFocus();
            return;

        }

        if (mEmail.isEmpty()) {
            email.setError("Please enter your email");
            email.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        if (mPassword.isEmpty() || mPassword.length() < 8) {
            password.setError("please enter your password correctly");
            return;

        }

        Call<userResponse> call = newapi.login("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "password" , mEmail, mPassword);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<userResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<userResponse> call, Response<userResponse> response) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"response successful" + response.code(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),dashboard.class));

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<userResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"response Failed" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: check if their user is found as such in your db

Comment: there is a user by that name

Comment: so ... he does log in as a signed up user? what is the problem?

Comment: everything works well but i cant get a response from the server

Comment: the values i passed to the call seems right when i log the values ,but no response from the server

Comment: Test same api using postman. It seems to be an api issue. You must be getting some response code from server on api hit

Comment: the api is working fine  ,when i tried with postman with  the sane credentials